# Reversing the direction of the arrow in gb4e

Tags: arrows, linguistics, gb4e

Any suggestions on how to reverse the direction of the arrow such that it starts from the word je pointing to the word very in the example below?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\primebars
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex\atcenter{\arrowalign{
\lb{TP}  \lb{T} & \emph{je_{j}} & ] \lb{BeP} & \lb{PredP} \emph{very  
important_{i}} & ] \lb{Be} t_{j}  ] \lb{PredP} & \lb{DP} this task ]  
\lb{PredP} t_{i}]]]] \cr
&\fillright\pu&\link1&\fillleft\vrule & \cr}}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you consider another solution that doesn't use the `gb4e` under arrow system?

Comment: Sure! Especially if with nicer or simpler output? Actually, I have been looking for  codes that produce arrows in the bracketed sentence contexts.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go. You simply have to reverse the `\pu` and `\vrule` arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\primebars
\begin{document}

% original arrow
\begin{exe}
\ex\atcenter{\arrowalign{
\lb{TP}  \lb{T} & \emph{je_{j}} & ] \lb{BeP} & \lb{PredP} \emph{very  
important_{i}} & ] \lb{Be} t_{j}  ] \lb{PredP} & \lb{DP} this task ]  
\lb{PredP} t_{i}]]]] \cr
&\fillright\pu&\link1&\fillleft\vrule & \cr}} % here
\end{exe}

% reversed arrow 
\begin{exe}
\ex\atcenter{\arrowalign{
\lb{TP}  \lb{T} & \emph{je_{j}} & ] \lb{BeP} & \lb{PredP} \emph{very  
important_{i}} & ] \lb{Be} t_{j}  ] \lb{PredP} & \lb{DP} this task ]  
\lb{PredP} t_{i}]]]] \cr
&\fillright\vrule&\link1&\fillleft\pu & \cr}} % and here
\end{exe}
```

[image]